# Trying to make a Cubic Yard Calculator but the formula is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, html

Was looking to create a cubic yards calculator but not really the savviest at JS. When I work with smaller numbers they give me the right answer but as I get bigger they get really off. The formula should be cubic yards = (length in feet * width in feet *(depth in inches/12))/27. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```js
    var l = 0;
    var w = 0;
    var d = 0;
    var lw = 0;
    var y = 0;
    function calc(obj) {
        var e = obj.id.toString();
        if (e == 'length') {
            l = Number(obj.value);
            w = Number(document.getElementById('width').value);
            d = Number(document.getElementById('depth').value);
        } else {
            l = Number(document.getElementById('length').value);
            w = Number(obj.value);
            d = Number(document.getElementById('depth').value);
        }
        lw = l * w;
        y = (lw * (d/12))/27;
      if (isNaN(y)) {
       document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = "Please enter valid numbers.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('total').value = +y.toFixed(4);
        document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = +y.toFixed(4);
        document.getElementById('yard-check').innerHTML = " yards&#179;";
      }
    }
```

```html
    <form name="addem" action="" id="addem" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="outerwrapper">
    <div class="inputwrapper">
      <div class="inputfield">
        <p>Length</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="length" name="length" onkeyup="calc(this)" step="any" placeholder="in feet" /><span style="padding-left:2%;">ft</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputfield">
        <p>Width</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="width" name="width" onkeyup="calc(this)" step="any" placeholder="in feet" /><span style="padding-left:2%;">ft</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputfield">
        <p>Depth</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="depth" name="depth" onkeyup="calc(this)" step="any" placeholder="in inches" /><span style="padding-left:2%;">in</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cubictotal">
      <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="0" />
      <h3 id="p-yards"><span id="update">0 yards&#179;</span><span id="yard-check"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please post sample data that is correct and one set that is in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking/overcomplicating getting the values in the `calc` function from DOM. Simplify the whole `if/else` section by referencing the value of each input directly; your math wasn't the problem at all.

```js
function calc() {
  const l = +document.getElementById('length').value;
  const w = +document.getElementById('width').value;
  const d = +document.getElementById('depth').value;

  const y = (l * w * (d / 12)) / 27;

  if (isNaN(y)) {
    document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = "Please enter valid numbers.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('total').value = +y.toFixed(4);
    document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = +y.toFixed(4);
    document.getElementById('yard-check').innerHTML = " yards&#179;";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="addem" action="" id="addem" autocomplete="off">
  <div id="outerwrapper">
    <div class="inputwrapper">
      <div class="inputfield">
        <p>Length</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="length" name="length" onkeyup="calc(this)" step="any" placeholder="in feet" /><span style="padding-left:2%;">ft</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputfield">
        <p>Width</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="width" name="width" onkeyup="calc(this)" step="any" placeholder="in feet" /><span style="padding-left:2%;">ft</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputfield">
        <p>Depth</p>
        <p><input type="text" id="depth" name="depth" onkeyup="calc(this)" step="any" placeholder="in inches" /><span style="padding-left:2%;">in</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cubictotal">
      <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="0" />
      <h3 id="p-yards"><span id="update">0 yards&#179;</span><span id="yard-check"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: YAY this worked! thanks! Quite new to pulling variables so this was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your calculation actually. The problem is the `onkeyup` event and the object that you pass along with it. You only caught two cases:

1. Onkeyup was triggered by the length input
2. Onkeyup was triggered by the width input

The third option - the depth input triggers the onkeyup event - is not explicitly coded and thus it will default to the `else` case, which is case 2. The result is that both the `w` and `d` parameters will be set to whatever the value of the depth is supposed to be. Just see what happens when you last update the width or the length inputs; there's the correct answer!

I suggest that you always find the dimension elements by ID so that the calculation doesn't rely on whatever actually triggers the calculation.

Comment: I thought about creating additional lines to pull the depth but it never seemed to work well/it wouldn't provide me with the correct answer. This was helpful! Thanks!